# Seeking advice for organizing my Git

Tags: git, github, repository

I'd like to make a repository to contain all my school project, instead of making a new one for each new project. This repository should contain projects from different programming classes and different languages, so I intend to divide them following this criteria. Finally, each of these "subfolders" should contain the effective projects. How can I accomplish this task using GitHub and Git? Thank you

Structure:

school-projects

|-IT_Class

```
   |-Project1
   |-Project2
```

|-Android_Class

```
   |-Project3
   |-Project4
```

Comment: The same way you would do to add any directory or file to git. git doesn't care about the structure of your files, the programming language of the file it contains, etc. You're completely free to organize your files the way you want to. What's the concrete problem? I don't think it's a good idea, but if you want to do so, just do it.

Comment: If you use GitLab, you can get private namespaces for repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Create your repository on GitHub (name it "School" for example). Then clone that repository to your computer using `git clone https://github.com/YourUserName/School.git`. Then create your folders inside the "School" repository on your computer like so:

```
School
├── Android_Class
│   ├── Project1
│   └── Project2
└── IT_Class
    ├── Project1
    └── Project2
```

and proceed with the usual `git add .` (stages all [changed] files), `git commit -m "Added new Project"`, `git push` routine.

Comment: Some GUI-Clients are [Sourcetree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) and [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish this task. You can upload the local folders to `github` using the `command line`,or create it in github.Follow the [link](https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/#repository) to learn more.And files can be organsied according to your wish.